# Moving rows with animation gliding effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a container I have four rows. Each with a different number of columns. Whenever I click on each row it should move to its next row. However on clicking the final row (any row which comes to the final position) it should move to the first row.I am able to move the rows using the following code but i need to move the rows with animation  gliding effect(that is how to move the rows with animation).

```
$(".row").each(function() {
  $(this).click(function(){
    if (($(this).next()).length === 1 )
    {
      $(this).insertAfter($(this).next());
    }
    else
    {
      $(this).insertBefore($(this).siblings().first());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post your html?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want like this?

```
$(".row").each(function() {
  $(this).click(function(){
    if (($(this).next()).length === 1 )
    {
      $(this).insertAfter($(this).next()).hide().show('slow');;
    }
    else
    {
      $(this).insertBefore($(this).siblings().first()).hide().show('slow');;
    }
  });
});
```

[fiddle  link](https://jsfiddle.net/gnanavelr/ndtxr5vj/)